# Can not change font-awesome icon color on click

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

I am not able to give color on **i** tag of font-awesome.

Instead I can give color to i:before and it works.

But the problem is when I want to change the color on click, :before element does not work.

I tried to give css like i:active:before{color:green} but it did not work.

```html
    <!--HTML-->
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
```

```css
    <!--CSS-->
    i:active::before{color:green}
```

I expect the output should be the green icon on click..but it just do not work. Please help.

Comment: using the SVG version of the CSS one?

Comment: I do not use SVG version of the css.

Comment: remove `::before` it will work

Comment: I tried it after removing     ::before but it is not working.

Comment: Please add code snippet

Comment: Do you want the color to persist once you click? in that case go with JS

Comment: icon never call the :active until or unless it is inside a anchor tag (text-align: center;). You have to go with javascript to add active class to icon tag and then change the colour. It's like using div as an anchor ta

Answer (score 1):

You have to use JavaScript.

```
let icon = document.querySelector('i');
icon.addEventListener('click',function(){
  icon.style.color = "green";
})
```